# Не меняется курсор в FireFox

Tags: css, firefox

По событию `mousedown` создаётся под указателем новый элемент со своим набором стилей, в том числе собственный вид курсора.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").on("mousedown", function() {
    $("body").append("<div class='resizable'></div>")
  });
  $(document).on("mouseup", function() {
    $("div.resizable").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.resizable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  cursor: move;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style="width:100px" />
```

В Chrome и IE всё работает как надо, а вот Firefox вредничает: курсор остаётся тем же, что был до `mousedown`.

Comment: Скорее всего это ошибка FF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему, FF показывает курсор input'а до тех пор, пока нажата кнопка.
Можно попробовать исправить так (но код с mouseup кривой - надеюсь, он тут для примера):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").on("mousedown", function() {
    $(this).addClass("move-cursor")
    $("body").append("<div class='resizable'></div>")
  });
  $(document).on("mouseup", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("move-cursor")
    $("div.resizable").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.resizable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  cursor: move;
  background: #eee;
}

.move-cursor {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style="width:100px" />
```